# KeePass URL with space in Notes not working

Tags: keepass

I have a network path in the Notes section of a KeePass entry, it creates a broken link (stopping after the space):

[image]

Is there any other option besides renaming all folders in path to remove spaces? I have unsuccessfully tried:

- Replacing spaces with %20
- Enclosing the whole thing in quotes (double & single)
- Enclosing the whole thing in square brackets []
- Quickly searched keepass's site

Comment: Actually I think SPC in an URI is not allowed, so it should be encoded as `%20` instead. Read about *unreserved* characters ("ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"") in Appendix A of RFC 3986.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up trying to enclosing the whole thing in less/greater-then brackets <> & visually noticed it turned all the text into a link. However I got an error about file not found (it seems it interrupted anything after the first space as an argument. I took an old Microsoft office tip & added this to the beginning: `file:////`

So this ended up solving the issue:

`<file:////company.org\it-cave\Documentation\Infrastructure Design or Diagram\Maps of WiFi.pdf>`